# Difficulty including GLM into Visual Studio with OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glm

I have been trying to implement GLM (math library) into Visual Studio with OpenGL. I have followed and watched many online resources that point me to include only the GLM folder inside the downloadable zip file into Visual Studio. I believe I have also put the correct relative path in the additional include directories tab. I put the GLM folder into a file I named src/vendor, along with another header file that already works correctly. Visual Studio also is able to be include GLM as #include "glm/glm.hpp". The configuration is set properly as well, as in it matches debug/x86.

The issue is apparent when I build the project though, as it is saying that it cannot find any files with the path "src\vendor\glm\test\core\*randomheaderfiles*.

All the resources have not said to include the test file of the downloadable zip, or any other file for that matter, except the "glm" file. So what is the issue? I also get a warning saying "Two or more files with the name of glm.cpp will produce outputs to the same location", but they both have the same path of "src\vendor\glm\detail\glm.cpp", and I only found one of those files with that name there.

I did try to put the "test" file of the GLM downloadable zip file into the project as well, but that did not seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's a problem with how you have provided relative path to library in visual studio "Additional Include Directories" section. What happens when you right click on  #include "glm/glm.hpp" line in visual studio and say "Open document "glm/glm.hpp"? I am sure you have tried this but just minor check to see if include path is correct or not.